# Why can't I use sizeof in a preprocessor condition?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, sizeof

I understand that sizeof is an operator, which is evaluated at compile time to an integer constant.
But it seem it can not be used in the #if preprocessor directive like:

```
#if 4 == sizeof(int)
    typedef int Int32;
#endif
```

(cygwin-gcc 3.4.4 as well as Visual C++ 6.0 report compile errors)

Why is such usage not allowed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `sizeof` is evaluated at compilation time while directives are evaluated **before** compilation, and the part that does that is not the compiler, so it won't understand what `sizeof` means.

Comment: Actually preprocessing happens during compilation, just in one of the earlier phases. Evaluating `sizeof` happens in a later phase.

Comment: @sbi Preprocessing isn't a part of compilation - compiler usually runs preprocessor before the actual compilation, but you can instruct compiler not to do so. RichN's answer is 100% correct.

Comment: Well, I was wrong, but only in terminology: It's one of the phases of _translation_. According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476892/1479972#1479972, there's no phase called "compilation" either, so what's meant with that seems open to interpretation.

Comment: I could have sworn I've seen it work before. Maybe I'm mistaken though.

Answer (score 11):

The sizeof is a C operator. You can't use C code in preprocessor directives. Preprocessor directives are evaluated before the compilation takes place.

Comment: "==" is also a operator. The answer from RichN point the problem a bit clearer for me.

Comment: @felix0322: The preprocessor has its own `==` operator, which is the one used in preprocessor directives.