# Checking enum values at compile time

Tags: c, compiler-construction, assert

I'd like to check static initalizers at compile time. I'm implementing the macro CASSERT() from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807244/c-compiler-asserts-how-to-implement).

Now, I have this "strange" situation

```
typedef enum
{
    EQADC_CHAN_A_00 = 0,
    EQADC_CHAN_A_01,
    EQADC_CHAN_A_02,
    EQADC_CHAN_A_03,
    EQADC_CHAN_A_04,
    ...                 // Others
    EQADC_CHAN_MAX      // EQADC_CHAN_MAX = 62

} eQadc_tInputBiosId;
```

And I have a structure initialized like this:

```
const t_EQADC_Pin_Config EQADC_xPinConfig[EQADC_CHAN_MAX] = {
    { 123 },  /* EQADC_CHAN_A_00 */
    { 321 },  /* EQADC_CHAN_A_01 */
    ...       /* Others */
};
```

What is strange (to me...) is that the following statement

```
CASSERT(( sizeof(EQADC_xPinConfig)/sizeof(EQADC_xPinConfig[0]) ) != 62 );
```

works fine, and actually "passes" (i.e. compiles without errors).
Instead, this:

```
CASSERT(( sizeof(EQADC_xPinConfig)/sizeof(EQADC_xPinConfig[0]) ) != EQADC_CHAN_MAX );
```

does not (i.e. it actually generates an assertion, and stops the compiler.

Trying to figure out why this happens, I think that the problem is related to the value of EQADC_CHAN_MAX, that is not known at compile time, being an enum value. If this is the case, I still can't understand why this declaration

```
const t_EQADC_Pin_Config EQADC_xPinConfig[EQADC_CHAN_MAX]
```

actually instantiates the correct size for the array...
Any help on how I can (better) implement this is really appreciated.

**Edit**: my fault. The correct syntax is

```
CASSERT(( sizeof(EQADC_xPinConfig)/sizeof(EQADC_xPinConfig[0]) ) == EQADC_CHAN_MAX );
```

Furthermore, pay attention as declaring the array this way:

```
const t_EQADC_Pin_Config EQADC_xPinConfig[EQADC_CHAN_MAX] = { Initializers ....}
```

actually allocates the size of EQADC_CHAN_MAX elements, even if the number of *initialized* elements is not actually correct.
So, the right way to implement this is:

```
const t_EQADC_Pin_Config EQADC_xPinConfig[] = { Initializers ....}
CASSERT(( sizeof(EQADC_xPinConfig)/sizeof(EQADC_xPinConfig[0]) ) == EQADC_CHAN_MAX );
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Exactly how are you defining CASSERT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612322/why-cant-i-use-sizeof-in-a-preprocessor-condition) that discusses how sizeof is evaluated at compilation while directives are evaluated *before* compilation, so directives that depend on sizeof will not work.

If that doesn't help then can you run your compilation step with the -p option, or whatever it is for your compiler, to produce pre-processor output?  That might clarify why the predicate in your 2nd assertion doesn't evaluate to what you expect.

Also, why are you asserting that the size of that array is *not* 62?

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that `EQADC_CHAN_MAX == 62`?  Can you put in a `printf("%d", EQADC_CHAN_MAX)` to make sure?

Comment: You think he got the CASSERT() macro defined the wrong way round?