# View macro expanded version of source while debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am attempting to debug some C code using the visual studio debugger. I seems my choices are to view the source code or view the the disassembly. But what I would really like to view is the source code with all the macro's expended. Is that also possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual C++ the best you can have is a preprocessed file (C++ ->Preprocessor->Generate preprocessed file). This will give you a huge file of C++ code with all macros expanded. Still macro expansions [will be single lines - no line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116126/how-can-i-make-the-preprocessor-insert-linebreaks-into-the-macro-expansion-result).

This is one of the reasons why macros are very problematic to use for complicated code and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an option like that is available in Visual Studio.  It would probably be necessary to run the preprocessor on the code first and then compile the pre-processed file and use that as the source.