# C++ Preprocessor string literal concatenation

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476892/poster-with-the-8-phases-of-translation-in-the-c-language) regarding how the **C** preprocessor should handle string literal concatenation (phase 6). However, I can not find anything regarding how this is handled in C++ (does C++ use the **C** preprocessor?).

The reason I ask is that I have the following:

```
const char * Foo::encoding = "\0" "1234567890\0abcdefg";
```

where `encoding` is a static member of class `Foo`. Without the availability of concatenation I wouldnt be able to write that sequence of characters like that.

```
const char * Foo::encoding = "\01234567890\0abcdefg";
```

Is something entirely different due to the way `\012` is interpreted.

I dont have access to multiple platforms and I'm curious how confident I should be that the above is always handled correctly - i.e. I will always get `{ 0, '1', '2', '3', ... }`

Comment: Just Out of curiosity - why are you using char* instead of std::string?

Comment: @David Relihan: Why would anyone use a `std::string` for an immutable string constant? Not even taking into account that a `char *` might be required by the client code specification (like some API).

Comment: @AndreyT: "Why would anyone use a std::string for an immutable string constant?" Because they wanted to lexicographically compare strings (and don't want to take into account whether they are constants or whatnot)?

Comment: You could write it as `"\000123..."`. A numeric escape sequence may have at most three octal digits. The fourth digit is not included as part of the escape sequence; it's an ordinary character.

Comment: @Rob: I hadn't thought of that. Nice solution :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The language (C as well as C++) has no "preprocessor". "Preprocessor", as a separate functional unit, is an implementation detail. The way the source file(s) is handled if defined by so called *phases of translation*. One of the phases in C, as well as in C++ involves concatenating string literals.

In C++ language standard it is described in 2.1. For C++ (C++03) it is phase 6

> 6 Adjacent ordinary string literal
>   tokens are concatenated. Adjacent wide
>   string literal tokens are
>   concatenated.

Comment: Right, I was looking for a document detailing this for C++. I was not able to find one - though I found C details readily.

Comment: AndreyT - you forgot to mention that `"\0"` is converted to the target character set _before_ string literals are merged.  This is the key to the question at hand.

Comment: @D.Shawley: I don't immediately understand the importance of that. You mean without that the `\0` part could still merge with `12` part and form an octal char literal `\012`? Hm... I'd say that the important part here is actually phase 4, not 5, when each string literal is converted into an independent *preprocessing token*. This alone already takes care of the potential issue with `\012`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will be handled as you describe, because it is in stage 5 that,

> Each source character set member and escape sequence in character constants and
>   string literals is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character
>   set (C99 §5.1.1.2/1)

The language in C++03 is effectively the same:

> Each source character set member, escape sequence, or universal-character-name in character literals and string literals is converted to a member of the execution character set (C++03 §2.1/5)

So, escape sequences (like `\0`) are converted into members of the execution character set in stage five, before string literals are concatenated in stage six.

Comment: Right - I get that much. My question is whether this is transparent across C/C++. And, if so, where I can reference that documentation.

Comment: @ezpz:  Sorry; I missed that you were interested in the compatibility between the two.  Yes, the results are the same for both C and C++; I've added the language from the C++ standard, which effectively says the same thing.  You can find where to get the relevant standards documents from this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Comment: +1 for actually mentioning the different stages of translation since this is why `"\0" "12"` is not the same as `"\012"`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the agreement between the C++ and C standards. Most, if not all, C++ implementations use a C preprocessor, so yes, C++ uses the C preprocessor.

Comment: More precisely, the C++ standard and C standard agree on certain translation phases, and in preprocessor directives, and every C++ implementation I know of uses a C preprocessor.  I like to keep the difference between what the Standards say and what implementations do.