# Why is the following shell command working when executed directly in command line, but not working when executed through C program using popen/system?

Tags: c, linux, command-line, adb, popen

The command is : `ps -c -p | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2,6-10,13 | grep 'R'`

I am running it through adb shell. Basically, I want a list of processes (and certain parameters) which are currently in the run queue. This is working fine if I run it directly through the shell.

However, if I put it in a C program and cross-compile it to run on Android, it's not working. Only `ps -c -p` is working (I have checked that). But on running this `ps -c -p | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2,6-10,13 | grep 'R'`, I get the output :

```
usage: tr [-cds] SET1 [SET2]

Translate, squeeze, or delete characters from stdin, writing to stdout

-c/-C  Take complement of SET1
-d     Delete input characters coded SET1
-s     Squeeze multiple output characters of SET2 into one character

tr: Needs 1 argument
usage: cut OPTION... [FILE]...

Print selected parts of lines from each FILE to standard output.

-b LIST select only these bytes from LIST.
-c LIST select only these characters from LIST.
-f LIST select only these fields.
-d DELIM    use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter.
-s  do not print lines not containing delimiters.
-n  don't split multibyte characters (Ignored).

cut: Needs -fcb
```

I think the output of `ps -c -p` is not being conveyed to `tr`, which doesn't convey it to `cut`.
Can you please suggest what's the issue?

Here's the code I am using:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define BUFSIZE 128

    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
        char *cmd4 = "ps -c -p | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2,6-10,13 | grep 'R'";    
        system(cmd4);

        FILE *fp;


        char buf[BUFSIZE];
     // Another method
    if ((fp = popen(cmd4, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening pipe4!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        // Do whatever you want here...
        printf("cmd 4 running!");
        printf("OUTPUT: %s", buf);
    }

    if(pclose(fp))  {
        printf("Command not found or exited with error status4\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code making the call in your C program?

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Made the edits.

Comment: If you're on Linux, run it under `strace`, follow all child processes using the `-f` option, and **learn what happens to command line arguments when passed through something like `popen()`**.

Comment: For people who doubt that the pipeline is executing, take note that the error messages come from the second and third stages of the pipeline, not the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell, you're using the following command:

```
ps -c -p | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2,6-10,13 | grep 'R'
```

In C, you're passing the following to `system` (and later to `popen`):

```
ps -c -p | tr -s  | cut -d  -f 2,6-10,13 | grep 'R'
```

See the difference?  Quotes need to be escaped in C source code.  Also, when you have trouble like this, be sure to output the relevant data so you can see what is actually happening instead of what you planned.  A simple `puts(cmd4)` would have revealed this instantly.

Comment: In case you're wondering why this compiles without error, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2837469/103167