# How Linux C code find conf file(usually in /etc)

Tags: c, linux, project

I know when I install a Linux app from source ,I execute `./configure --sysconfdir=/etc`, then this app's conf file(such as `httpd.conf`) will goto `/etc`.

But **from the view of source code**, how do source code know the conf file is under `/etc` when parse it. I mean the code like `fopen("/../../app.conf", "r");` is determined before we install it, will the configure file change source code or some other mechanism exist ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `configure` script will generate the necessary `Makefile` that will use the C compiler's `-DMACRO=content` functionality to essentially inject C preprocessor `#define MACRO content` statements into the compilation units. So, `sysconfdir` could be used via Make rules:

```
foo.o: foo.c
        $(CC) -DCONFDIR=$(sysconfdir) -o $@ $<
```

(That says to build the `foo.o` object file when `foo.c` is updated; to build it, use the `$(CC)` variable to run the C compiler, define `CONFDIR` with the contents of `$(sysconfdir)` (supplied via the `./configure` script), put output into the target file (`$@`) and give the source file (`$<`) as the lone input to the compiler.))

Then the C code in `foo.c` could use it like this:

```
 FILE *conf;
 if (conf = fopen(CONFDIR "/foo", "r")) {
     /* read config file */
 } else {
     /* unable to open config, either error and die or supply defaults */
 }
```

Note the C [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476892/poster-with-the-8-phases-of-translation-in-the-c-language) is performed before compiling the program -- super convenient for exactly this kind of use.

More details here: http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/Installation-Directory-Variables.html#Installation-Directory-Variables

Comment: For Apache, look in the `include/ap_config_layout.h.in` file for some `#define` statements that are used elsewhere in the program. Rsync configures `RSYNCD_SYSCONF` in `configure.in`, which is used in `clientserver.c` function `load_config()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `./configure`, it typically generates a makefile that includes the command options for the C compiler.  These options will include `-D...` options that (in effect) "#define" various CPP symbols.  One of these will have the "/etc" value that you supplied when you ran `./configure --sysconfdir=/etc`.

From there, the "/etc" string gets compiled into the code anywhere that the source code uses the #defined symbol.

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick answer, so what source code would be look like in that way? I've looked into rsync and httpd's source code but I didn't find THE code parsing conf file. It would be greatly appreciated if you can offer an example.

Comment: In the case of httpd, look for the SERVER_CONFIG_FILE symbol.  How the configuration process goes from --sysconfigdir to that is (ahem) complicated, and involves some apache specific M4 macros.  Look at "configure.in" and "acinclude.m4".  And "main.c" contains places where SERVER_CONFIG_FILE is used.

Comment: Oh yeah, seems I have a lot work to do now, Thank you very much