# Macro expansion of __typeof__ to function name

Tags: c, macros, posix, c-preprocessor, typeof

I wrote the following code in plain **C**:

```
#define _cat(A, B) A ## _ ## B
#define cat(A, B) _cat(A, B)
#define plus(A, B) cat(cat(plus,__typeof__(A)),__typeof__(B))(A, B)

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double x = 1, y = 0.5;
    double r = plus(x, y);
    printf("%lf",r);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I would like the macro `plus` to be expanded becoming a function name which contains the types of the parameters. In this example I would like it to expand the following way

```
double r = plus(x, y)
...
/* First becomes*/
double r = cat(cat(plus,double),double)(x, y)
...
/* Then */
double r = cat(plus_double,double)(x, y)
...
/* And finally */
double r = plus_double_double(x, y)
```

However all I got from the preprocessor is

```
double r = plus___typeof__(x)___typeof(y)(x,y)
```

and gcc will obviously refuse to compile.
Now, I know that **typeof** evaluates at compile-time and it is my understanding that a macro is only prevented from being evaluated when it is contained in second macro which directly involves the stringify `#`and the concatenation `##` tokens (here's the reason why I split `cat` in the way you see). If this is right, why doesn't `__typeof__(x)` get evaluated to double by the preprocessor? Seems to me that the behaviour should be perfectly clear at build time. Shouldn't `__typeof__(x)` evaluate to `double` before even going in `_cat`?

I searched and searched but I couldn't find anything... Am I doing something really really stupid?

I'm running Mac OS X Mountain Lion but I'm mostly interested in getting it work on any POSIX platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this does not work is **typeof** is not a macro but a reserved word in the gcc's dialect of C and is thus handled *after* the preprocessor has finished its work. A good analogy would be the sizeof operator which is not a macro either and is not expanded by the preprocessor. To do (approximately) what you want (pick a different function based on the type of the arguments) try the _Generic construct (new in C11)

Answer (score 2):

Macro expansion occurs before C token analysis (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479972/1583175 for a diagram of the phases of translation)

The macro preprocessor is unaware of the type information -- it merely does text processing

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor knows nothing about types, only about textual tokens. `__typeof__()` gets evaluated by the compiler pass, after the preprocessor has finished performing macro replacements.